# What is $\int (1-e^{-x})^n dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, mathematica, beta-function

For my purposes, $n$ is a non-negative integer, and $x > 0$. I didn't know how to evaluate this integral, so I plugged it into Mathematica. It told me the solution is

$(-1)^n B(e^x; -n, n+1)$

I have never before seen the incomplete Beta function defined for negative integers, though I did find a reference with a definition over negative integers [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X07007664).

Confusingly, asking Mathematica to evaluate this solution for a particular value of $n$ always gives `ComplexInfinity`. Does this mean Mathematica doesn't know a definition for the incomplete Beta function with negative integers? And if not, why would it provide me with such a solution?

Due to the conflicting results from Mathematica, I am not confident this solution is actually correct/complete. Can somebody point me towards a more detailed solution?

Comment: The bounds of integration are very important. What are you trying to use?

Comment: I am most interested in integrating from 0 to some positive real. However, it doesn't seem to matter what I choose... the result always involves an incomplete Beta function with a negative integral first argument.

Comment: **Hint:** Expand the integrand using the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), and then switch the order of summation and integration.